# What is best architecture to store huge videos and lot log file with processed data?

Tags: hadoop, semantics, hbase, neo4j

It is a research project. We will record lot videos everyday, and metadata with log data would be saved in semantic model, RDF or OWL. The video would be used to download or processed on server.Everyday we would add lot data. What is the best storage solution?
Some Options

1. use the Hbase. the binary files would be stored in HDFS. Hbase supportw semantic well.
2. use HDFS + Neo4j. Neo4j is just for semantic mode. So we just record the binary file's path in the RDF or OWL file.  Then Java would process the logic.
3. Lustre+ Hbase or Neo4j. The Lustre would store the large video files, and Hbase/Neo4j is used for semantic data.

What is the Best one, or some better solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing RDF triples one of the triple stores listed below can be a solution:

- AllegroGraph, http://www.franz.com/agraph/allegrograph/
- OWLIM, http://www.ontotext.com/owlim
- BigData, http://www.systap.com/bigdata.htm

For an extensive list please see http://www.w3.org/wiki/LargeTripleStores